# How can I evaluate this integral? - measure theory

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $u \in L^{p}(\Omega)$, where $\Omega$ is an open bounded domain in $R^n$ and $2\leq p <\infty$. Let $u_{+}$ the positive part of $u$. I am trying to show that to show that $\int_{ \{ u \leq 0 \}} u_{+} ln u_{+}     - u_{+} \ dx = 0$ .

It appears to be true because  we have $lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} x ln x - x = 0 $ and informally I can think that $"0 ln 0 - 0 = 0 "$, then $\int_{ \{ u \leq 0 \}} u_{+} ln u_{+}     - u_{+} \ dx  = \int_{ \{ u \leq 0 \}}  0 = 0 $ . Someone could give me a help with a rigorous proof or a counterexample?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You're integrating the *positive* part of $u$ on the set $\{u\leq 0\}$. Then the integral is 0 assuming you've defined $0\ln 0=0$, which is reasonable from a limit point of view.